# RoR: Updating user password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form `<% form_for(@player) do |f| %>` that displays the user's password

```
<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.text_field :password %>
```

I want to hide the password (just show a blank text box), and only update the password on submit if the text box is not blank. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: confused. reads as 'you want to hide the field but use it if entered' huh?  I'm sure it'll make more sense if you re-word and maybe add some to put it in context.

Comment: I'm assuming, possibly incorrectly, that he just means the text field for password would not have the current password in it, and if the user enters a new password in it THEN it would try to save that new password otherwise it would ignore that input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your player model (I'm assuming it's the Player model that represents your user), this code does want you need:

```
# user will be able to edit her profile without providing password
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_confirmation_of :password, :allow_blank => true

# you may also need to set the required length
validates_length_of :password, :within => 6..40, :allow_blank => true
```

And in your view, just use `password_field` instead of text_field. With `password_field`, you don't have to set the value to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

[Ryan Bates' Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) has everything you need and more.

Look at the user model the the show notes (`before_save` hook and `validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create`).

And never use a text_field for passwords. Use password_field instead (that will do the hiding for you).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I'm clear on what you're asking but here's what I would suggest. In the view:

```
<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, :value => "" %>
```

Then in your controller:

```
if param[:player][:password].blank? == false
  @player.password == param[:player][:password]
end
```

I believe this will set things up such that it only saves when its not nil and not empty. Also make the :password field NOT an attr_accessible variable in your model...

EDIT: to be clear on that last comment. If it is not attr_accessible it won't be updated by the model instance method `update_attributes`.